# Riverpod: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, bool>' of 'value' Flutter

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, state-management, riverpod

I have an app that gets the data from a `FutureProvider` and everything is working fine. Except I can't change the state of other `providers` in my app. And when I do, I get this error

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, bool>' of 'value'

Here are all my `providers` that are needed for this example

```
final connectionTypeProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose((_) async {
  final ConnectionType connectionType = await kGetConnectionType();
  return connectionType;
});
```

```
    final loadFromDatabase =
        StateProvider<Map<String, bool>>((_) => {"loadFromDatabase": false});
```

```
    final userAuthProvider = StateProvider<Map<String, bool>>((_) => {
          'signedIn': false,
          'loaded': true,
          'signInWasDissmised': false,
          'userIsConnectedToInternet': true
        });
```

And here is how I use it. Please, reference the comments in the code.

```
    class GetPage extends ConsumerWidget {
      const GetPage({@required this.appState});
    
      final Map<String, bool> appState;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
        StateController<Map<String, bool>> fromDatabase = watch(loadFromDatabase);
        StateController<Map<String, dynamic>> isConnected = watch(userAuthProvider);
        return watch(connectionTypeProvider).when(
            data: (data) {
              if (data == ConnectionType.none) { // Until here it works just fine
                // Check database for previous data and if there is, show it to the user
                final String database = 'Data';
                if (database.isNotEmpty) {
                  fromDatabase.state = { // Here the problem happens
                    ...fromDatabase.state,
                    "loadFromDatabase": true
                  };
                  print(fromDatabase);
                  return Home();
                } else {
                  isConnected.state = {  // Here the problem happens
                    ...isConnected.state,
                    'userIsConnectedToInternet': false
                  };

                  // ... Other code
```

So what's the problem and how can I solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Map<String, dynamic>.from(yourData)

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
    StateController<Map<String, dynamic>> isConnected = watch(userAuthProvider);
```

And :

```
final userAuthProvider = StateProvider<Map<String, bool>>((_) => {
```

Change your StateController to `<Map<String, bool>>`